# How to remove the clips of the Honda Emblem. Safely

Tags: honda, civic, parts, body, bumper

Can someone suggest me how to remove the clips/pins behind the emblem of the front grille of a Honda Civic 2014 EX Sedan. I wanna replace the grille because it's cracked.

I saw many tutorials in youtube where people break these pins to replace it by a red limited edition emblem, but this new one is glued and not hooked.

Can this emblem be removed safely to put it in another grille?

Tips, links or videos please?

Very appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With a flat thin small screwdriver, you should be able to wiggle under it and pry up a little bit, then move to the opposite side of the same fastener and do the same thing. Working back and forth should bring it off of the pin without issue. The fastener thing may end up a little bent, but as long as the pin is okay, I'd suggest you'd be in good shape. This may be a little bit harder considering the fasteners are recessed, but you should still be able to get at it in this method without too much of an issue.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. I thought that it was very delicate that I was worried to break them. I gonna try what you adviced me. Do you know where can I find, just in case, the fasteners?

Comment: Any good auto paint store will have the push fasteners, that or a good hardware store.

Comment: @MaximusDecimus - Do be careful with them, as you can still break the pin off of the emblem. They aren't that stout, but this is about the only way to remove them. Just go easy and gentle with them and you should be good.